# Is there a way to upload Images using Laravel Jobs

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload image in laravel jobs but i keep getting this error `"Serialization of 'Illuminate\\Http\\UploadedFile' is not allowed"`

In my controller i try to save the image to `wasabi cloud` and then passing it to the job by doing this

```
public function store(ThreadRequest $request)
    {
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->attachment->extension();
        $request->attachment->storeAs('public/attachments', $imageName, 'wasabi');

        $this->dispatch(CreateThread::fromRequest($request, $imageName));
        return redirect()->route('threads.index');
    }
```

And then in my job i accept `$imageName` as `attachment` and did this

```
    public function handle(): Thread
    {

        $thread             = new Thread([
            'title'         => $this->title,
            'body'          => Purifier::clean($this->body),
            'category_id'   => $this->category,
        ]);

        $thread->authoredBy($this->author);
        $thread->save();

        return $thread;
    }
}
```

I tried passing the image from my controller to my job, although i know you need to save the image temp and pass it to laravel job but that's where i am confused.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't pass the full request to the job, as that contains a lot more information than you need. Instead, pass in `$request->all()` so only the relevant data gets passed.

Comment: So how should it be then??

Comment: You should store your image, and pass the path to the job

Comment: @Lk77 that is my question, how do i achieve this. I keep seeing store image and pass path.

Comment: @japahen look for the storing file section of the doc : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#storing-files and also the file uploads one : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#file-uploads there should be everything you need, you then transmit the result of the storeAs function to the job (aka the path)

Comment: @Lk77 Nice one mate :)